# It tastes like chicken(pronunciation-unstressed end consonant?)

Tags: pronunciation, connected-speech

When a particular new food is given to you, and you tasted it, you say:

> "Nice! It taste**S** like chicken!''

Do you say it with stressed S sound or you don't have to? Because I heard from BBC learning English that a native said ''**it taste like chicken''** which supposedly  like ''**it tastes like chicken''** 
(But I'm not sure)

LINK: [BBC laboratory grown meat](https://youtu.be/w0K2idFdBZY)

Was the native wrong?

Comment: Yes, I do pronounce the final **s**, a lazy speaker would be more likely to say "tase like". But do you pronounce the **t** in **it**?

Comment: Yes, I do. Grammatically that's correct right?

Comment: Nothing to do with grammar but pronunciation. It is quite hard to pronounce each **t** unless speaking very slowly and deliberately. More usually the first **t** is a [glottal stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop).

Comment: Please quote the source of "BBC learning English".

Comment: @WeatherVane, hello I've just added the link above (@0.37-0.40 secs and 1.36 roughly). For me, the ''it tastes like chicken'' pronunciation, pronouncing it will be ''it **teysts** like chicken, NOT ''it **teys** like chicken''. That's the ideal right? Am I weird by following the ideal of pronouncing it?

Comment: Thanks John. I am sorry to disappoint you but I hear two esses, although the final one is slight. So I noticed no missing consonants in "tastes".

Comment: Oh I see, my headphone's left part just got broken so maybe I didn't hear the subtleness of its ''s'' sound. Hmm, I dont like that. Much thx.

Comment: Yes, the pronunciation in the recording *is* subtle. I had to listen several times to convince myself that the final **s** is spoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be difficult to hear the two /s/‘s in words ending in /sts/. But even if you can’t hear it, you should think of the second /s/ as being there: it is supposed to be there in the accents that are typically taught to learners. (I feel tempted to say “standard” accents, but some people argue that there aren’t really any standard accents of English.)